# Dependency Injection on Custom ActionFilter with Unity.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm having a problem with custom action filter and dependency injection. Here is my code:

**PageCount.cs**

```
public class PageCount : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    [Dependency]
    public IVisitorService _visitorService { get; set; }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        _visitorService.AddVisitorCount();
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**IVisitorService.cs**

```
public partial interface IVisitorService
{
    int GetVisitorsCount();
    void AddVisitorCount();
}
```

**VisitorService.cs**

```
public partial class VisitorService : IVisitorService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Visitor> _visitorRepository;

    public VisitorService(IRepository<Visitor> visitorRepository)
    {
        _visitorRepository = visitorRepository;
    }

    public int GetVisitorsCount()
    {
        Visitor v = _visitorRepository.Get(1);

        return v.VisitCount;
    }

    public void AddVisitorCount()
    {
        Visitor v = _visitorRepository.Get(1);
        v.VisitCount += 1;
        _visitorRepository.Update(v);
    }
}
```

**UnityConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterComponents()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    // identity
    container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new InjectionConstructor(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
        container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory( o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));

    container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
    container.RegisterType<IGameService, GameService>();
    container.RegisterType<IGenreService, GenreService>();
    container.RegisterType<IVisitorService, VisitorService>();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

**UnityMvcActivator.cs**

```
public static void Start() 
{
    var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();

    FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
    FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

    // TODO: Uncomment if you want to use PerRequestLifetimeManager
    // Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
}
```

**Error**

> The current type,
>   GameCommerce.Infrastructure.Services.Visitors.IVisitorService, is an
>   interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that MVC isn't using the container that you setup in your `RegisterTypes` method in **UnityConfig.cs**. At the end of `RegisterTypes` in **UnityConfig.cs**, you set `DependencyResolver.Current` to a container that you've created within the method, but later on in **UnityMvcActivator.cs**, `DependencyResolver.Current` is overwritten with `UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer()`, which does not contain your registrations.

I recommend that you use the **UnityConfig.cs** class provided with the `Unity.Mvc` package without your modifications to the `RegisterTypes` method as follows:

**UnityConfig.cs**

```
public class UnityConfig
{
    #region Unity Container
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    });

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the configured Unity container.
    /// </summary>
    public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
    {
        return container.Value;
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>Registers the type mappings with the Unity container.</summary>
    /// <param name="container">The unity container to configure.</param>
    /// <remarks>There is no need to register concrete types such as controllers or API controllers (unless you want to 
    /// change the defaults), as Unity allows resolving a concrete type even if it was not previously registered.</remarks>
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
        // container.LoadConfiguration();

        // TODO: Register your types here
        container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new InjectionConstructor(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
        container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory( o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));

        container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
        container.RegisterType<IGameService, GameService>();
        container.RegisterType<IGenreService, GenreService>();
        container.RegisterType<IVisitorService, VisitorService>();
    }
```

This way `DependencyResolver.Current` will only get set once, in **UnityMvcActivator.cs**.

Comment: thanks. for the reply but it throws null reference. **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."** from this method call **_visitorService.AddVisitorCount();** on PageCount.cs

Comment: A null reference exception means that your dependencies are being properly resolved now. Can you debug and see what's null? Is `_visitorService` null? Is the `_visitorRepository` inside of the `AddVisitorCount()` method null? Or the is `_visitorRepository` returning a null `Visitor` inside of the `AddVisitorCount()` method?

Comment: @Correy Smith Hi, I add the break point in the **VisitorService.cs**, the constructors and other stuffs works well until the step reach **public IVisitorService _visitorService { get; set; }**. The **_visitorService** field is null.

Comment: @markoverflow I've setup a repository [on GitHub here](https://github.com/coreyasmith/UnityRegistrations/tree/master/UnityRegistrations/UnityRegistrations) that mirrors your code. Can you compare it to your code base and see what's different? Based on the information you've provided, you shouldn't be getting a null reference anymore.

Comment: thanks. i compare the codes in the git, the problem was i used this code **filters.Add(new PageCount());** in **RegisterGlobalFilters**. The reason that it is returning null is if I don't use [PageCount] in the controller that i will use. Like my program don't need to have [PageCount] on login page controller, and that is my default page, so it will throw null, but if I add [PageCount] it will work. So I just remove **filters.Add(new PageCount());** and it works. thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about splitting your attribute into a "passive" attribute as discussed in this article?

http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/

From your implementation, you are using property injection since constructor injection is unavailable because you can only pass constants and literals to an attribute.  But you really should be using constructor injection because your dependency is required and the won't work without the reference to IVisitorService. (Property injection commonly denotes an optional dependency.)

If you follow the example in the article, you'd create a nice separation of concerns and ease the issue you are having with the IoC framework.